# Get month's start time and end time in non UTC timezone in java

Tags: java, spring, date, datetime, time

I'm trying to obtain the start and end times of a specific month in a particular timezone, specifically "Asia/Kolkata" (UTC+05:30).

For instance, below are start and end times for September 2023.

Start Time: 2023-09-01 00:00:00

End Time: 2023-09-30 23:59:59

I've implemented the following functions in Java:

```java
public static Long getStartTimeStampOfMonth(Month month, Year year) {
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year.getValue(), month, 1);
    LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(startDate, LocalTime.MIN);
    ZonedDateTime istDateTime = startDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    return Timestamp.valueOf(istDateTime.toLocalDateTime()).getTime();
}

public static Long getEndTimeStampOfMonth(Month month, Year year) {
    LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(year.getValue(), month, 1);
    LocalDate endDate = startDate.withDayOfMonth(startDate.lengthOfMonth());
    LocalDateTime endDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(endDate, LocalTime.MAX);
    ZonedDateTime istDateTime = endDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"));
    return Timestamp.valueOf(istDateTime.toLocalDateTime()).getTime();
}
```

However, I've noticed that the above code returns the start and end times based on the timezone configured on the machine. Even though I've explicitly specified ZoneId.of("Asia/Kolkata"), it doesn't produce the desired results.

When I tested the code for SEPTEMBER 2023 on a machine set to the UTC timezone, I got the following output:

Start Time: 1693526400000

End Time: 1696118399999

However, I want the output to be consistent, regardless of the machine's timezone:

Start Time: 1693506600000

End Time: 1696098599999

Please help me identify what I might be missing or suggest an alternative approach.

Comment: I've read this a few times but still can't understand what's being asked, not a knock, I just don't understand.  I'm confused as to why the timezone should even be considered, September begins at 00:00:00 on the 1st in every timezone.

Comment: @lane.maxwell - They're calculating a timestamp corresponding to the first instant of a month and the last instant of a month.  Those timestamps are UTC-based, but the date and time are local to a given time zone.

Comment: @lane.maxwell Time zone matters because days, and therefore months, start earlier in the east than in the west. When a new day arrives in Tokyo Japan, it is still ”yesterday” in Toulouse France. Likewise, upon a new day in Toulouse, it is still “yesterday” in Toledo Ohio US.

Comment: @lane.maxwell Another thing about time zone: Days do not always start at 00:00. Some dates in some time zones start at other times such as 01:00.

Comment: Avoid the hacky and long outdated `Timestamp` class. In its day it was also only meant for timestamps to and from SQL databases. Instead convert via `Instant`. Your issue is caused by your call to `toLocalDateTime()`.  The *local* in some java.time class names means *without time zone*, so in this call you are throwing the time zone, Asia/Kolkata, away.

Comment: A detail, since you have got a `Year` object (nice), for me the elegant conversion to `LocalDate` would be `year.atMonth(month).tDay(1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
YearMonth
.of( 2023 , Month.NOVEMBER )
.atDay( 1 ) 
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) 
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

… and:

```
YearMonth
.of( 2023 , Month.NOVEMBER )
.plusMonths( 1 )
.atDay( 1 ) 
.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ) 
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

## Details

> September 2023

Use [`java.time.YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/YearMonth.html) class to represent a month.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2023 , Month.NOVEMBER ) ;
```

> start and end times of a specific month in a particular timezone, specifically "Asia/Kolkata" (UTC+05:30).

Get the dates first.

```java
LocalDate startDate = ym.atDay ( 1 );
LocalDate endDate = ym.atEndOfMonth ( );
```

Get the first moment of the first day. Doing so requires a time zone. Do not assume the day starts at 00:00, as some dates in some zones may start at an another time such as 01:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day.

```java
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" );
ZonedDateTime startZdt = startDate.atStartOfDay ( z );
```

> End Time: 2023-09-30 23:59:59

Your example is incorrect. If you abut your monthly periods, you will be missing the last second of that last day.

Better to define your spans of time as Half-Open, where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*. So a month starts at the first moment of the first day, and runs up to, but does not include, the first moment of the *following* month. Using this arrangement, you'll not lose that last second.

```
ZonedDateTime endZdt = endDate.plusDays ( 1 ).atStartOfDay ( z );
```

Apparently you want to represent these two moments as a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of  first moment of 1970 as seen in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

Your attempt at getting that count…

```
Timestamp.valueOf(istDateTime.toLocalDateTime()).getTime();
```

… is incorrect in two ways:

- You called `toLocalDateTime` which loses any notion of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Do not use `LocalDateTime` objects when working with moments. For more explanation, see correct [Answer by Johnson-Pint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77218362/642706).
- You use a terribly flawed legacy class `Timestamp` which was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Avoid the legacy classes, and use only *java.time* classes.

To adjust our two moments into an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from the temporal meridian of UTC, extract `Instant` objects.

```java
Instant startInstant = startZdt.toInstant ( );
Instant endInstant = endZdt.toInstant ( );
```

From there you can get your count of milliseconds.

```java
long start = startInstant.toEpochMilli ( );
long end = endInstant.toEpochMilli ( );
```

I do not recommend you represent moments in this fashion. A count of milliseconds is ambiguous, as it is just an integer with no context, and this creates ambiguity. 1970-01-01T00:00Z is only one of dozens of [common epoch references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(computing)#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing). Furthermore, a count from epoch cannot by deciphered by humans. This means errors may easily escape notice.

I recommend you communicate date-time values textually, using standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. For a moment as seen in UTC, an example would be `2023-10-02T20:53:59Z`. The `T` separates the date portion from the time portion. The `Z` is an abbreviation for `+00:00`, an offset of zero.

Here is a complete code example.

```java
package work.basil.example;

import java.time.*;

public class MonthMoments
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of ( 2023 , Month.NOVEMBER );
        LocalDate startDate = ym.atDay ( 1 );
        LocalDate endDate = ym.atEndOfMonth ( );

        ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Kolkata" );
        ZonedDateTime startZdt = startDate.atStartOfDay ( z );
        ZonedDateTime endZdt = endDate.plusDays ( 1 ).atStartOfDay ( z );

        Instant startInstant = startZdt.toInstant ( );
        Instant endInstant = endZdt.toInstant ( );

        long start = startInstant.toEpochMilli ( );
        long end = endInstant.toEpochMilli ( );

        System.out.println ( "startZdt = " + startZdt );
        System.out.println ( "endZdt = " + endZdt );

        System.out.println ( "startInstant = " + startInstant );
        System.out.println ( "endInstant = " + endInstant );

        System.out.println ( "start = " + start );
        System.out.println ( "end = " + end );
    }
}
```

When run:

```
startZdt = 2023-11-01T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
endZdt = 2023-12-01T00:00+05:30[Asia/Kolkata]
startInstant = 2023-10-31T18:30:00Z
endInstant = 2023-11-30T18:30:00Z
start = 1698777000000
end = 1701369000000
```

To work with pairs of moments, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. That library includes the [`Interval`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) class, to represent a span of time as a pair of `Instant` objects. That class offers several handy methods such as `contains`, `abuts`, and `intersection`. And that class parses/generates text in standard ISO 8601 format with two moments separate by a slash.

```
Interval monthInterval = Interval.of( startInstant , endInstant ) ;
```

Comment: Thanks for `YearMonth` . Didn't know about this, this can make implementation clearer. But I don't understand why do you want to include next day's 00:00:00 sec in last day. I want to keep it till 23:59:59, since that's when the day ends.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat No, the day ends at the first moment of the next day. There is an infinity of split seconds between second 59 and the first moment of the next day. If you timestamp database queries, you will never retrieve the rows stored with values having a time of 23:59:59.001, 23:59:59.333, 23:59:59.789, etc.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat A series of your incorrectly defined months will result in a series of gaps, missing a thousand milliseconds between every month.

Comment: @user85421 Thanks, now this makes sense. Thanks @Basil Bourque for pointing out this.

My implementation returns `1696098599999` as end timestamp which is `30 September 2023 23:59:59.999 GMT+05:30` which does include `23:59:59.1` but yes, keeping it to next second and making condition exclusive is a better idea.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat Not to run this point into the ground, but to further the explanation: Your end timestamp of `30 September 2023 23:59:59.999 GMT+05:30` will miss values in a database like Postgres that uses microseconds. So your query will not find rows like `…  23:59:59.999001`, `…  23:59:59.999002`, `…  23:59:59.999003`,  etc. And queries among *java.time* objects resolving to nanoseconds will miss values such as `…  23:59:59.999000001`, `…  23:59:59.999000002`, `…  23:59:59.999000003`, etc. Using Half-Open approach neatly solves the entire problem.

Answer (score 5):

The local time zone is being introduced when you convert from `ZonedDateTime` to a `Timestamp`:

```
return Timestamp.valueOf(istDateTime.toLocalDateTime()).getTime();
```

Since you're going through a `LocalDateTime`, the `Timestamp.valueOf` method will presume the local time zone.

From [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#valueOf-java.time.LocalDateTime-):

> `public static Timestamp valueOf(LocalDateTime dateTime)`
>
> Obtains an
> instance of `Timestamp` from a `LocalDateTime` object, with the same year, month, day of month, hours, minutes, seconds and nanos date-time value as the provided `LocalDateTime`.
>
> ***The provided `LocalDateTime` is interpreted as the local date-time in the local time zone.***

Instead, you can create the `Timestamp` from an `Instant`:

```
return Timestamp.from(istDateTime.toInstant()).getTime();
```

Though, since you appear to be after a `long` in terms of *milliseconds*, you could just skip the `Timestamp` type entirely:

```
return istDateTime.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

Comment: A very nicely explained answer. Since an old-fashioned `java.sql.Timestamp` is not the end goal, I unconditionally agree in skipping that hack of a class.